# The Python script configuration for a Big Query job requires a sourceUri value, but there is no sourceUri

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-bigquery

When attempting to write a Python script for a Google BigQuery job.  I'm following the configuration guidelines found in the job [configuration properties](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs).  It indicates the configuration parameter configuration.query.tableDefinitions.(key).sourceUris[] is required.  This parameter is described as "The fully-qualified URIs that point to your data in Google Cloud Storage."  However, the query I'm submitting runs on a data set within Big Query, not data in Cloud Storage.  I've tried leaving the format parameter empty or pointing it to a storage location where I have other tables, but the script still throws an error.  Can anyone tell me the proper way to handle this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `configuration.query.tableDefinitions` parameter should be optional.  If you are querying only data stored in BigQuery tables, then you should be able to omit the entire `tableDefinitions` parameter.  The `sourceUris` parameter should only be required if a `tableDefinitions` object is present.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs#configuration.query.tableDefinitions

Comment: Danny, I'm trying to output the results to a table, thus I need the table definition.  That in turn forces me to come up with the uri, and there is my problem.

Comment: If you are attempting to output the results to the table, you should only need to specify the [`configuration.query.destinationTable` parameter](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs#configuration.query.destinationTable).  The table definitions are only for source tables **living in Cloud Storage (for example) instead of BigQuery** and referenced within the query SQL, which it sounds like you do not need to use.